Back button always displaying `Home Page` in spite of correct screen stacking with expo-router
Being a beginner with ReactJS trying to build a react-native app, I saw that expo was a good option to go about it. But for some reason, I can't figure out a good way to use expo-router from the documentation.
I'm not exactly sure how much information would be required to receive any help, but I will first write about my folder structure, then how the screens look like. Finally, I will also write down parts of the code. Please let me know if anything else is required for this problem.
My folder structure looks like this:
app/
├── settings/
│   ├── _layout.tsx
│   ├── index.tsx
│   └── auth/
│       ├── _layout.tsx
│       ├── index.tsx
│       ├── login.tsx
│       └── signup.tsx
├── _layout.tsx
├── [missing].tsx
├── chat.tsx
└── index.tsx

As expo-router is a file-based routing system, I expect the screens to stack like Home -> Settings -> Auth, but when I go from the Home screen to Settings page, and then from there move to the Auth page, somehow the back button still takes me back to Home screen instead of Settings page.
For reference, this is my Home page:

From there, I move to the Settings page clicking the button on the top-right corner (title bar of the Home page), which looks like:

If I click on the Login / Signup button, we go to the third page Auth, but the back button still shows Home Page. It looks like this:

My app/_layout.tsx looks like:
import { Stack, router } from "expo-router";
import { ThemeProvider, DefaultTheme, DarkTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { StatusBar, useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { SettingsButton } from "../src/components";

export default function HomePageLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      <Stack
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, headerTintColor: "white", headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "black" }, headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "bold" } }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="index"
          options={{
            title: "Home Page", headerShown: true, headerRight: () => (
              <SettingsButton
                color="white"
                onPressFunction={() => router.push("settings")}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="settings"
          options={{ title: "Settings", headerShown: true }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="[missing]"
          options={{ title: "Page Not Found", headerShown: true }}
        />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}


My app/index.tsx looks like this:
import { Stack, router } from "expo-router";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { CustomButton, bodyStyles } from "../src/components/";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={[bodyStyles.container, { width: "100%" }]}>
        <View style={bodyStyles.buttonContainer}>
          <CustomButton
            buttonTitle="Chat"
            onPressFunction={() => console.log("Chat pressed")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

settings/_layout.tsx:
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function SettingsLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="auth" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}

settings/index.tsx:
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { router } from "expo-router";
import { bodyStyles, CustomButton } from "../../src/components";

export default function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={[bodyStyles.container, bodyStyles.buttonContainer]}>
      <CustomButton
        buttonTitle="Login / Signup"
        onPressFunction={() => router.push("/settings/auth")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

settings/auth/_layout.tsx:
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function AuthLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="login" options={{ headerShown: false, presentation: "modal" }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="signup" options={{ headerShown: false, presentation: "modal" }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}

settings/auth/index.tsx:
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { CustomButton, bodyStyles } from "../../../src/components";
import { router } from "expo-router";

export default function AuthScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={bodyStyles.container}>
      <Text style={bodyStyles.header1}>Welcome user!!</Text>
      <Text style={bodyStyles.header2}>Please login or create account!</Text>
      <View style={bodyStyles.buttonContainer}>
        <LoginButton />
        <SignupButton />
        <CustomButton
          buttonTitle="Go Back"
          onPressFunction={() => router.back()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

On this last page, when I call router.back() when I press the Go Back button, I go to the Settings page. That should mean the last screen on the stack is Settings page, not the Home Page, but still the back button is set to Home Page from the Auth page.
I have given as much context as I think would be necessary. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Also please feel free to let me know if I am not following any best practice that react-native should follow.
Thank you in advance!
Edit: I realized that if I put headerShown: true option for the screens under settings/_layout or auth/_layout, I get another level of header that takes be back to the Settings page. That means, every time I call another layer of <Stack> in _layout.tsx, it just creates a separate stack where my screens live. And the topmost header in the screen always points to the Home Page because that is the only other option on the topmost stack.
So my question essentially is, what is the ideal way of defining nested stacks that act as a single stack, even when the routes are nested?

I have figured out a way to manually put back button on the headers for the pages where the back button was not appearing.
For example, I change the app/settings/_layout.tsx file to this:
import { Stack, router } from "expo-router";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Platform } from "react-native";

export default function SettingsLayout() {
  const backIcon = Platform.OS === "ios" ? "chevron-back" : "arrow-back-sharp";

  return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        headerTintColor: "white",
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "black" },
        headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "bold" },
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: "Settings",
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name={backIcon}
              size={25}
              color="white"
              onPress={() => router.back()}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="auth" options={{ title: "Authorize" }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}

which gives me an okayish solution for all the platforms that looks close to the native solution.
But being a non-native solution, it also introduces some issue. For example, in Android the titles appear very close to the headerLeft button wherever the non-native solution (headerLeft) is applied.
This solution, while patching the problem temporarily, still does not completely solve the problem of creating a single screen stack while having multiple nested routes with multiple _layout.tsx files.
I am posting the solution for now, but if anyone has a better solution that implements the same back button in a native way, please answer this question.
